# WebSocket - Ports - Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: ssl, websocket, wss

I'm trying to get a wss connection between two servers but I'm always getting Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

What ports can I use for wss connection? Where can I find out which I can use or where can I setup these?

I'm really looking for a long time now. Any small tips and hints are appreciated.

Best regards,
CabCon.

Comment: Websockets use standard HTTP ports by default, so 80 for HTTP (WS) and 443 for HTTPS (WSS).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thank you! I'm getting now 'Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404'...